# Mutable parameters in Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Looking at this question: [How to dynamically do filtering in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8)

The issue is to truncate a stream after a filter has been executed. I cant use [limit](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit%28long%29) because I dont know how long the list is after the filter. So, could we count the slements after the filter?

So, I thought I could create a class that counts and pass the stream through a map.[The code is in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8/22856514#22856514).

I created a class that counts but leave the elements unaltered, I use a Function here, to avoid to use the lambdas I used in the other answer:

```
class DoNothingButCount<T > implements Function<T, T> {
    AtomicInteger i;
    public DoNothingButCount() {
        i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }
    public T apply(T p) {
        i.incrementAndGet();
        return p;
    }
}
```

So my Stream was finally:

```
persons.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.size > 12)
    .filter(u -> u.weitght > 12)
    .map(counter)
    .sorted((p1, p2) -> p1.age - p2.age)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .stream()
    .limit((int) (counter.i.intValue() * 0.5))
    .sorted((p1, p2) -> p2.length - p1.length)
    .limit((int) (counter.i.intValue() * 0.5 * 0.2)).forEach((p) -> System.out.println(p));
```

But my question is about another part of the my example.

```
collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().
```

If I remove that line the consequences are that the counter is ZERO when I try to execute limit. I am somehow cheating the "efectively final" requirement by using a mutable object.

I may be wrong, but I iunderstand that the stream is build first, so if we used mutable objects to pass parameters to any of the steps in the stream these will be taken when the stream is created.

My question is, if my assumption is right, why is this needed? The stream (if non parallel) could be pass sequentially through all the steps (filter, map..) so this limitation is not needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer

> My question is, if my assumption is right, why is this needed? The
>   stream (if non parallel) could be pass sequentially through all the
>   steps (filter, map..) so this limitation is not needed.

As you already know, for **parallel** streams, this sounds pretty obvious: this limitation is needed because otherwise the result would be non deterministic.

Regarding **non-parallel** streams, it is not possible because of their current design: each item is only visited once. If streams did work as you suggest, they would do each step on the whole collection before going to the next step, which would probably have an **impact on performance**, I think. I suspect that's why the language designers made that decision.

---

### Why it technically does not work without `collect`

You already know that, but here is the explanation for other readers.
From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed
>   when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are
>   consumed only as needed.

Every *intermediate operation* of `Stream`, such as `filter()` or `limit()` is actually just some kind of setter that initializes the stream's options.

When you call a *terminal operation*, such as `forEach()`, `collect()` or `count()`, that's when the computation happens, processing items following the pipeline previously built.

This is why `limit()`'s argument is evaluated before a single item has gone through the first step of the stream. That's why you need to end the stream with a terminal operation, and start a new one with the `limit()` you'll then know.

### More detailed answer about *why not allow it for parallel streams*

Let your stream pipeline be `step X > step Y > step Z`.

We want parallel treatment of our items. Therefore, if we allow step Y's behavior to depend on the items that already went through X, then Y is non deterministic. This is because at the moment an item arrives at step Y, the set of items that have already gone through X won't be the same across multiple executions (because of the threading).

### More detailed answer about *why not allow it for non-parallel streams*

A stream, by definition, is used to process the items in a *flow*. You could think of a non-parallel stream as follows: one single item goes through all the steps, then the next one goes through all the steps, etc. In fact, the doc says it all:

> The elements of a stream are only visited once during the life of a
>   stream. Like an Iterator, a new stream must be generated to revisit
>   the same elements of the source.

If streams didn't work like this, it wouldn't be any better than just do each step on the whole collection before going to the next step. That **would actually allow mutable parameters** in non-parallel streams, but it would probably have a performance impact (because we would iterate multiple times over the collection). Anyway, their current behavior does not allow what you want.

Comment: You said: "If one step in the process needs to know about the result of the processing of all the items in the previous steps, then the whole stream idea does not work anymore.". Why? In the question linked the user wants to get the top 50% after a filter has been applied (so we can not use a limit because we dont know how many there will be). Why do you think it goes against the idea of streams.

Comment: Because, IMHO, using a stream means you want to process each item the same way (like in a car factory: add stuff on the current car then pass it on to the next step). Here, if you need to know a result depending on all items, then the processing is not the same for each item. That's why a terminal operation is needed.

Comment: Sounds good to me. But we still have filter and limit, after a filter and limit some of the items will not be processed

Comment: Well `filter` filters all items the same way, it does not need to know about all items in advance, just what the current one looks like.

Comment: As for `limit`, it sill does not depend on the *future*, only the past items need to be remembered.

Comment: Take a look at the edited version of my post, maybe you'll be more satisfied ;)

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now. +1. But I will leave it unaccepted for a while to give time to someone to give a more in deep argument.

Comment: The "past vs future" argument does not convince you enough? :)