# How to get a range of items from stream using Java 8 lambda?

Tags: java, filter, lambda, java-8

In a previous question [ [How to dynamically do filtering in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8) ] Stuart Marks gave a wonderful answer, and provided several useful utilities to handle selection of topN and topPercent from stream.

I'll include them here from his original answer :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Criterion {
    Stream<Widget> apply(Stream<Widget> s);
}

Criterion topN(Comparator<Widget> cmp, long n) {
    return stream -> stream.sorted(cmp).limit(n);
}

Criterion topPercent(Comparator<Widget> cmp, double pct) {
    return stream -> {
        List<Widget> temp =
            stream.sorted(cmp).collect(toList());
        return temp.stream()
                   .limit((long)(temp.size() * pct));
    };
}
```

My questions here are :

[1] How to get top items from 3 to 7 from a stream with certain amount of items, so if the stream has items from A1, A2 .. A10, the call to

```
topNFromRange(Comparator<Widget> cmp, long from, long to) = topNFromRange(comparing(Widget::length), 3L, 7L)
```

will return { A3, A4, A5, A6, A7 }

The simplest way I can think of is get the top 7 [ T7 ] from original, get the top 3 [ T3 ] from original, and then get T7 - T3.

[2] How to get top items from top 10% to top 30% from a stream with certain amount of items, so if the stream has items from X1, X2 .. X100, the call to

```
topPercentFromRange(Comparator<Widget> cmp, double from, double to) = topNFromRange(comparing(Widget::length), 0.10, 0.30)
```

will return { X10, X11, X12, ..., X29, X30 }

The simplest way I can think of is get the top 30% [ TP30 ] from original, get the top 10% [ TP10 ] from original, and then get TP30 - TP10.

What are some better ways to use Java 8 Lambda to concisely express the above situations ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

User skiwi already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22917334/1441122) the first part of the question. The second part is:

> (2) How to get top items from top 10% to top 30% from a stream with certain amount of items....

To do this, you have to use a similar technique as `topPercent` in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855465/1441122) to the other question. That is, you have to collect the elements into a list in order to be able to get a count of the elements, possibly after some upstream filtering has been done.

Once you have the count, then you compute the right values for `skip` and `limit` based on the count and the percentages you want. Something like this might work:

```
Criterion topPercentFromRange(Comparator<Widget> cmp, double from, double to) {
    return stream -> {
        List<Widget> temp =
            stream.sorted(cmp).collect(toList());
        return temp.stream()
                   .skip((long)(temp.size() * from))
                   .limit((long)(temp.size() * (to - from)));
    };
}
```

Of course you will have to do error checking on `from` and `to`. A more subtle problem is determining how many elements to emit. For example, if you have ten elements, they are at indexes [0..9], which correspond to 0%, 10%, 20%, ..., 90%. But if you were to ask for a range from 9% to 11%, the above code would emit no elements at all, not the one at 10% like you might expect. So some tinkering with the percentage computations is probably necessary to fit the semantics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Close enough to what I was looking for, I'll work out the details, thanks !

Comment: I have updated my answer to also include a form of what you are doing, but then with using Collectors, perhaps it could also be interesting for the original question of criteria?

Comment: @skiwi Interesting, using the finisher function of a collector to turn the collection back into a stream. I'm not sure whether it's necessarily better or worse than just declaring a local variable. (The lambda parameter is used like a local in this case.) It's a useful technique to keep in mind for the future, though.

Answer (score 89):

To get a range from a `Stream<T>`, you can use `skip(long n)` to first skip a set number of elements, and then you can call `limit(long n)` to only take a specific amount of items.

Consider a stream with 10 elements, then to get elements 3 to 7, you would normally call from a `List`:

```
list.subList(3, 7);
```

Now with a `Stream`, you need to first skip 3 items, and then take 7 - 3 = 4 items, so it becomes:

```
stream.skip(3).limit(4);
```

As a variant to @StuartMarks' solution to the second answer, I'll offer you the following solution which leaves the possibility to chain intact, it works similar to how @StuartMarks does it:

```
private <T> Collector<T, ?, Stream<T>> topPercentFromRangeCollector(Comparator<T> comparator, double from, double to) {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toList(),
        list -> list.stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .skip((long)(list.size() * from))
            .limit((long)(list.size() * (to - from)))
    );
}
```

and

```
IntStream.range(0, 100)
        .boxed()
        .collect(topPercentFromRangeCollector(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i), 0.1d, 0.3d))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will print the elements 10 through 29.

It works by using a `Collector<T, ?, Stream<T>>` that takes in your elements from the stream, transforms them into a `List<T>`, then obtains a `Stream<T>`, sorts it and applies the (correct) bounds to it.

Comment: If you skip the first 10% of items, then there is only 90% items left in the stream, how to get the items from the original 30%, because the 30% from the 90% is not the original 30%, am I correct ?

Comment: @Frank You will need to calculate those numbers in advance.

Comment: @Frank I have updated the answer to also include a variant that works with chaining streams together.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for your effort. So what's the difference from a user standpoint ? When to use which one ? Any efficiency/accuracy differences ? What I can see is more steps involved and seems more complex, is there a way to simplify it to the form : Criterion topPercentFromRange(Comparator<Widget> cmp, double from, double to) , which is more intuitive.

Comment: @Frank I would personally prefer to chain methods, as that are the essentials of using streams, I do not like static methods, unless absolutely neccessary. That is the only real difference as far as I reckon.