# How can I use IntStream.range with map to create a new List from a pre-existing List. This is just for research purposes

Tags: java, list, higher-order-functions

I have an initial Integer List ('''numbers = List.of(2,2,4,6,8,243,11,17,19);''') and I wanted to attempt to carry out a Functional Program to take the first 5 numbers from ***numbers***, square them then put them in a new List.

I know how to create new odd and even lists from ***numbers***:

```
private static List<Integer> createOddListFP(List<Integer> list) {  
    return list.stream().filter(element -> (element % 2 != 0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
private static List<Integer> createEvenListFP(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(element -> (element % 2 == 0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This code returns an empty List and I am a bit confused as to where I am going wrong or if it's even possible. I was attempting to do it all in one line like the previous methods.

```
 private static List<Integer> tenListFP(List<Integer> list) { //should take first 5 elements, square them and return a new List
    return IntStream.range(list.indexOf(0), list.indexOf(4)).map(element -> element * element).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: See [answer by skiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22917334/5133585) specifically.

Comment: List<Integer> squareList = List.of(2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 243, 11, 17, 19)
                .stream()
                .map(number -> number * number)
                .limit(5)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(squareList);
Try this.

Comment: @VaibS thanks alot, yes it did.