# How to benefit from Java 8's parallelStream?

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I asked a question about dynamic filtering using Java 8 at [ [How to dynamically do filtering in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8) ], Stuart Marks answered it wonderfully and gave some sample code to test with at : https://gist.github.com/stuart-marks/10076102.

Since I'm new to Java 8 and so I wonder if the following lines would make the program run faster on multi-core workstations with lots of data to process, at least theoretically :

```
//  widgetList.stream().filter(compositePredicate).forEach(System.out::println);
    widgetList.parallelStream().filter(compositePredicate).forEach(System.out::println);

//  compositeCriteria.apply(widgetList.stream()).forEach(System.out::println);
    compositeCriteria.apply(widgetList.parallelStream()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Would relacing "widgetList.stream()" with "widgetList.parallelStream()" speedup the process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to test it. However note that:

- `System.our.println` is a synchronized method, so the terminal operation is essentially sequential
- only the filtering can therefore benefit from the parallelisation
- a parallel stream will probably be a gain for fairly large lists or for computationally intensive filtering operations