# Dynamic filter chaining Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a code like

```
private void processFiles() {
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(Configurations.SOURCE_PATH))
                    .filter(new NoDestinationPathFilter()) //<--This one
                    .filter(new NoMetaFilesOrDirectories()) //<--and this too
                    .forEach(
                            path -> {
                                new FileProcessorFactory().getFileProcessor(
                                        path).process(path);
                            });
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As of now I have various other methods, which are same as the above one, with only difference in the filters. Some methods have additional filters, some have different or none.

Is it possible, that I create a collection of filters required for a condition and pass in dynamically. And all the filters in the collection are applied on the stream. I do not want to hard-code the list of filters being applied.
I want to make it configuration based.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use [`Files.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-):

```
private void processFiles(final Path baseDir, final Consumer<? super Path> consumer,
    final Collection<BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes>> filters)
    throws IOException
{
    final BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> filter = filters.stream()
        .reduce((t, u) -> true, BiPredicate::and);

    try (
        final Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(baseDir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, filter);
    ) {
        stream.forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

Yes, this will mean converting your filters...

See also the javadoc of [`BiPredicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) and [`BasicFileAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html); in particular, `BiPredicate` has a `.and()` method which you will find useful in your situation.

Comment: I guess that won't help me. The code structure would change from .filter to .and But still would remain in code. I want to make it configuration based

Comment: You didn't tell anything about configuration based... Moreover, note that unlike you, I correctly close the stream.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
private void processFiles(List<Predicate<Path>> filterList) {
    Predicate<Path> compositeFilter=filterList.stream().reduce(w -> true, Predicate::and);
    try {
        Files.walk(Paths.get(Configurations.SOURCE_PATH))
             .filter(compositeFilter)
             .forEach(path -> {
                        new FileProcessorFactory().getFileProcessor(
                                path).process(path);
                    });

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don’t need to write your lambda expression as a statement here. Instead of `path -> { new FileProcessorFactory().getFileProcessor(path).process(path); }` you can simply write `path -> new FileProcessorFactory().getFileProcessor(path).process(path)`…