# Is there an elegant way of applying an array of filters in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, reduce

Is there a way to use `reduce` or a similar method to apply an array of filters to an array of objects?

Right now, I have this:

```
private void applyManyFilters(long[] initialData, LongPredicate... filters) {
    LongStream stream = Arrays.stream(initialData);
    for (LongPredicate filter : filters) {
      stream = stream.filter(filter);
    }
    long[] dataToUse = stream.toArray();

    // Use filtered data
}
```

A more elegant solution would look something like this:

```
private void applyManyFilters(long[] initialData, LongPredicate... filters) {
    long[] dataToUse = Arrays.stream(filters).reduce(Arrays.stream(initialData), (a, b) -> a.filter(b)).toArray();

    // Use filtered data here
}
```

Of course, the example above doesn't compile because both parameters to `reduce` need to be `LongPredicate`, not `LongStream`.  I'm curious if the code above can be written in one line?

(P.S. Just to be clear, this is intended to be a question of how Java 8 works, not a question about style.  I do agree that the one-line approach is not nearly as readable as the loop.)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
private void applyManyFilters(long[] initialData, LongPredicate... filters) {
    long[] dataToUse = Arrays.stream(initialData)
                             .filter(v -> Arrays.stream(filters)
                                                .allMatch(f -> f.test(v)))
                             .toArray();
    // Use filtered data
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Merging the other two answers, you could also create a helper method for combining an array of filters. You could make that a nice utility method in a helper class for reuse anywhere in your code, along with overrides for the other predicates (`BiPredicate`, `DoublePredicate`, `IntPredicate`, and `Predicate`).

```
private void applyManyFilters(long[] initialData, LongPredicate... filters) {
    long[] dataToUse = Arrays.stream(initialData)
                             .filter(combine(filters))
                             .toArray();
    // Use filtered data
}
public static LongPredicate combine(LongPredicate... filters) {
    return Arrays.stream(filters)
                 .reduce(LongPredicate::and)
                 .orElse(x -> true);
}
```

Comment: Seeing as when `long[] initialData` gets streamed it is autoboxed to `Long` objects, is there any advantage to using `LongPredicate` over `Predicate<Long>`? If not it would simplify the code a lot to use the generic version imo

Comment: @flkes The entire purpose of having a `LongPredicate` is that nothing will get boxed in the above code, e.g. the `v` in the first example and the `x` in the second example are both `long`, not `Long`. Where do you believe boxing occurs?

Comment: doesnt `Arrays.stream(initialData)` return a `Stream<Long>` ?

Comment: @flkes No, [`Arrays.stream(long[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-long:A-) returns a [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html). Check the overloads.

Answer (score 5):

The solution with `reduce` would be to reduce your predicates to a single predicate using `LongPredicate::and` as demonstrated here:

```
//prints 6
public static void main(String[] args) {
    applyManyFilters(new long[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, l -> l % 2 == 0, l -> l % 3 == 0);
}

private static void applyManyFilters(long[] initialData, LongPredicate... filters) {
    Arrays.stream(initialData).filter(
            Arrays.stream(filters).reduce(l -> true, LongPredicate::and)
    ).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Added the idea from your answer of using `reduce(LongPredicate::and)` to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39538886/5221149), but as a reusable helper method.

Answer (score 3):

To continue on the answer @Andreas posted, you could make it a static generic function so it's more reusable:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> applyManyFilters(Stream<T> data, Predicate<T>... filters) {
    return data.filter(d -> Arrays.stream(filters).allMatch(f -> f.test(d)));
}
```

Comment: Added the idea from your answer of using a reusable helper method to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39538886/5221149), but for the method to return a combined predicate, so the use of it is more stream-like.