# Filter object from List if filter condition is multiple and coming dynamically

Tags: java, java-8

I have a requirement where I have to filter object from list based on multiple dynamic filter condition.

I have already written code by looping over objects and then all filter and returning false if any condition doesn't match. The code that I have written is as

```
    Map<String, String> obj1  = new HashMap<>();
    obj1.put("id", "1");
    obj1.put("name", "name1");
    obj1.put("dept", "IT");
    obj1.put("sex", "M");

    Map<String, String> obj2  = new HashMap<>();
    obj2.put("id", "2");
    obj2.put("name", "name2");
    obj2.put("dept", "IT");
    obj2.put("sex", "M");

    Map<String, String> obj3 = new HashMap<>();
    obj3.put("id", "3");
    obj3.put("name", "name3");
    obj3.put("dept", "DEV");
    obj3.put("sex", "F");

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> employees = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(obj1,obj2,obj3));

    Map<String, String> filterCondition = new HashMap<>();
    filterCondition.put("dept", "IT");
    filterCondition.put("sex", "M");

    List<Map<String, String>> filteredEmployee = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Map<String,String> employee:employees){
        if(isValid(filterCondition, employee)){
            filteredEmployee.add(employee);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(filteredEmployee);
```

isValid method is as

```
private static boolean isValid(Map<String, String> filterCondition, Map<String, String> employee) {
    for(Entry<String, String> filterEntry:filterCondition.entrySet()){
        if(!employee.get(filterEntry.getKey()).equals(filterEntry.getValue())){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve it if filters that I am getting is coming dynamically.

I have already seen some answer in stackoverflow as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8) ,but with no help

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: I can use that. But even with stream filter I am not able to think solution better then this.

Comment: Not a solution, but I would switch your conditional to avoid a potential NPE: `if (!filterEntry.getValue().equals(employee.get(filterEntry.getKey())))`

Comment: @DanW , Yes I forgot to add that. Actually I am doing String Comparision with Apache StringUtils which is null safe.

Comment: @Roshan - You can convert your conditions into a single Predicate and then use Stream.filter() - see my answer.

Comment: On a side note, you don't need an ArrayList specifically, so you can just use `List<Map<String, String>> employees = Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine all filters as a single Predicate (using stream, reduce, and predicate composition):

```
Predicate<Map<String, String>> allConditions = filterCondition
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(ThisClass::getAsPredicate)
        .reduce((employee) -> true, Predicate::and);
```

Then just use Stream.filter()

```
List<Map<String, String>> filteredEmployees = employees
        .stream()
        .filter(allConditions)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Helper function:

```
private static Predicate<Map<String, String>> getAsPredicate(Map.Entry<String, String> filter) {
    return (Map<String, String> employee) -> employee.get(filter.getKey()).equals(filter.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use for-loop with Stream:

```
    Stream<Map<String, String>> employeeStream = employees.stream();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : filterCondition.entrySet()) {
        employeeStream = employeeStream.filter(map -> entry.getValue()
                                          .equals(map.get(entry.getKey())));
    }
    List<Map<String, String>> filteredEmployee = employeeStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks , This is really helpfull. Good approach

Comment: @Roshan check the CodeConfident's answer - it's cleaner

Comment: @Xiaff - I actually enjoyed reading yours too; it's a style I wouldn't have thought of (you broadened my programming mind!)