# Optionally apply filter on stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to perform a "best match" on a list of objects. I thought to implement a cascading filter, with the goal to end up with only one object that eventually becomes the "best match". I have a list of ObjectA, and a single ObjectB which I am comparing the properties of. Is there a way to optionally apply a filter to a stream if there is more than one element?

Currently I have implemented it like this:

```
List<ObjectA> listOfObjectA;
ObjectB oB;
List<ObjectA> matchedByProp1 = listOfObjectA.stream()
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp1().equals(oA.getProp1())).collect(Collectors.toList());
if (matchedByProp1.isEmpty()) {
    // If no objects match, then return null
    return null;
} else if (matchedByProp1.size() == 1) {
    // If one object matches prop1, this is easy
    return matchedByProp1.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
}

// If more than one object is left, filter further by prop2
List<ObjectA> matchedByProp2 = matchedByProp1.stream()
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp2().equals(oA.getProp2()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (matchedByProp2.isEmpty()) {
    // If further filtering is not successful, return one from the previous set
    return matchedByProp1.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
} else if (matchedByProp2.size() == 1) {
    // If one object matches prop2, this is easy
    return matchedByProp2.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
}

// If more than one object is left, filter further by prop3
List<ObjectA> matchedByProp3 = matchedByProp2.stream()
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp3().equals(oA.getProp3()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (matchedByProp3.isEmpty()) {
    // If further filtering is not successful, return one from the previous set
    return matchedByProp2.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
} else if (matchedByProp3.size() == 1) {
    // If one object matches prop3, this is easy
    return matchedByProp3.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
}

// We still have too many options, just choose one
return matchedByProp3.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```

This works for this scenario, but it seems like a lot of repeated code. Moreover, ObjectA and ObjectB can switch, so I have had to repeat this code twice, once for a list of ObjectA, and once for a list of ObjectB. What I would like to do is something more like this:

```
ObjectA match = listOfObjectA.stream()
    .filter(oA -> oB.getProp1().equals(oA.getProp1()))
    .optionallyFilter(oA -> oB.getProp2().equals(oA.getProp2()))
    .optionallyFilter(oA -> oB.getProp3().equals(oA.getProp3()))
    .getFirst().orElse(null);
```

I've tried implementing this approach as follows, but ran into an issue where I'm trying to consume the stream twice.

```
private class Matcher<T, U> {
    private final U u;
    private final Stream<T> stream;

    public Matcher(U u) {
        this.u = u;
        stream = Stream.empty();
    }

    public Matcher(U u, Stream<T> stream) {
        this.u = u;
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public Matcher<T, U> from(Stream<T> stream) {
        return new Matcher<>(u, stream);
    }

    public Matcher<T, U> mustMatch(Function<T, Object> tProp, Function<U, Object> uProp) {
        return new Matcher<>(u, stream.filter(t -> tProp.apply(t).equals(uProp.apply(u))));
    }

    public Matcher<T, U> shouldMatch(Function<T, Object> tProp, Function<U, Object> uProp) {
        if (stream.filter(t -> tProp.apply(t).equals(uProp.apply(u))).count() > 0) {
            return new Matcher<>(stream.filter(t -> tProp.apply(t).equals(uProp.apply(u))));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Optional<T> get() {
        return stream.findFirst();
    }
}

ObjectA match = new Matcher<ObjectA, ObjectB>(oB, listOfObjectA.stream())
    .mustMatch(ObjectA::getProp1, ObjectB::getProp1)
    .shouldMatch(ObjectA::getProp2, ObjectB::getProp2)
    .shouldMatch(ObjectA::getProp3, ObjectB::getProp3)
    .get().orElse(null);
```

Now I could use a list collector in my Matcher class like I'm doing currently, but it seems like for just a simple condition collecting the stream into a list and re-streaming it seems unnecessary. Is there a better way of doing this? Note that in different uses of this there may be a different # of properties.

Comment: might be related I think... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8

Comment: You know that things like `matchedByProp1.stream().findFirst().orElse(null)` could be written as simple as `matchedByProp1.get(0)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood your logic:

```
List<Predicate<ObjectA>> props = Arrays.asList(
    oA -> oB.getProp1().equals(oA.getProp1()),
    oA -> oB.getProp2().equals(oA.getProp2()),
    oA -> oB.getProp3().equals(oA.getProp3()));

ObjectA previousChoice = null;

for(Predicate<ObjectA> p: props) {
    listOfObjectA = listOfObjectA.stream().filter(p).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(listOfObjectA.isEmpty()) return previousChoice;
    else {
        previousChoice = listOfObjectA.get(0);
        if(listOfObjectA.size() == 1) break;
    }
}
return previousChoice;
```

or without streams:

```
listOfObjectA = new ArrayList<>(listOfObjectA);
ObjectA previousChoice = null;

for(Predicate<ObjectA> p: props) {
    listOfObjectA.removeIf(p.negate());
    if(listOfObjectA.isEmpty()) return previousChoice;
    else {
        previousChoice = listOfObjectA.get(0);
        if(listOfObjectA.size() == 1) break;
    }
}
return previousChoice;
```

This could also become generified to handle your two scenarios:

```
static ObjectB get(List<ObjectB> list, ObjectA oA) {
    return get(list,
        oB -> oA.getProp1().equals(oB.getProp1()),
        oB -> oA.getProp2().equals(oB.getProp2()),
        oB -> oA.getProp3().equals(oB.getProp3()));
}
static ObjectA get(List<ObjectA> list, ObjectB oB) {
    return get(list,
        oA -> oB.getProp1().equals(oA.getProp1()),
        oA -> oB.getProp2().equals(oA.getProp2()),
        oA -> oB.getProp3().equals(oA.getProp3()));
}
static <T> T get(List<T> listOfT, Predicate<T>... props) {
    listOfT = new ArrayList<>(listOfT);
    T previousChoice = null;

    for(Predicate<T> p: props) {
        listOfT.removeIf(p.negate());
        if(listOfT.isEmpty()) return previousChoice;
        else {
            previousChoice = listOfT.get(0);
            if(listOfT.size() == 1) break;
        }
    }
    return previousChoice;
}
```

While the predicates look identical, they’re doing different things, assuming the `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` do not have a common base class defining these properties (otherwise it would be too simple). So this duplication is unavoidable. Trying to generify it even more using `Function` delegates in the predicates, is unlikely to make the code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the tricks you could play:

```
final ObjectA[] tmp= new ObjectA[1];
ObjectA match = listOfObjectA.stream()
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp1().equals(oA.getProp1()))
        .peek(oA -> tmp[0] = tmp[0] == null ? oA : tmp[0])
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp2().equals(oA.getProp2()))
        .peek(oA -> tmp[0] = oA)
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp3().equals(oA.getProp3()))
        .findFirst().orElse(tmp[0]);
```

Or:

```
final ObjectA[] tmp= new ObjectA[2];
ObjectA match = listOfObjectA.stream()
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp1().equals(oA.getProp1()))
        .peek(oA -> tmp[0] = oA)
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp2().equals(oA.getProp2()))
        .peek(oA -> tmp[1] = oA)
        .filter(oA -> oB.getProp3().equals(oA.getProp3()))
        .findFirst().orElse(tmp[1] == null ? tmp[0] : tmp[1]);
```

Comment: **never**, **never**, **never** use `Stream#peek()`... https://stackoverflow.com/a/33636457/5515060