# Filtering a list based on a fluctuating number of conditions

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, java-stream

I want to write code which will be able to use a number of conditions to filter down a list of objects but I want the number of conditions to fluctuate (sometimes filtering with 1 field and sometimes with all 3 fields).

In my situation I want the user to have the option of selecting 'any' for a certain field but then still apply the filter for the other fields.
In the situation below, the user can filter a list by the fields `x, y & z` but then they can also change one of the filters to 'any' making that filter unnecessary when actually filtering the list. The `getFilteredList`method takes the `String` value from each combo box and uses each `String` to filter the list unless a `String` is 'any' then it will accept any `String` from that field.

[image: combo boxes uses to input a filter option for each field]

I have written code below which would work for such situation but would get increasingly more inefficient when adding more filters in the future. (2 filters result in 4 return statements, 3 filters result in 8 and so on...).

```
private static ArrayList<Model> getFilteredList(ArrayList<Model> originalList, String x, String y, String z ){

    if(x.equals("any") && y.equals("any") && z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList;
    }
    if(x.equals("any") && y.equals("any") && !z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList.stream().filter(item -> item.getZ().equals(z)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
    if(x.equals("any") && !y.equals("any") && z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList.stream().filter(item -> item.getY().equals(y)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
    if(x.equals("any") && !y.equals("any") && !z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList.stream().filter(item -> item.getY().equals(y)&& item.getZ().equals(z)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
    if(!x.equals("any") && y.equals("any") && z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList.stream().filter(item -> item.getX().equals(x)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
    if(!x.equals("any") && y.equals("any") && !z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList.stream().filter(item -> item.getX().equals(x)&& item.getZ().equals(z)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
    if(!x.equals("any") && !y.equals("any") && z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList.stream().filter(item -> item.getX().equals(x)&& item.getY().equals(y)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
    if(!x.equals("any") && !y.equals("any") && !z.equals("any")) {
        return originalList.stream().filter(item -> item.getX().equals(x)&& item.getY().equals(y)&& item.getZ().equals(z)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
    return originalList;
}
```

Here's what `Model` would look like:

```
public class Model {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public String getZ() {
        return z;
    }
}
```

The code below will return a list where the `x` fields are equal to 'red', where the `y` fields are equal to 'medium' and where the `z` fields can be anything.

```
private static ArrayList<Model> items = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Model> filteredList = getFilteredList(items, "red", "medium", "any");
}
```

I'm unsure if there is an easier way to do my `getFilteredList` method, I have searched plenty but cannot find any simpler/more efficient implementation. In the future I hope to allow for 10+ filters with 'any' always being an option but my current solution is too long and would not be elegant at all. If anyone could provide any answers for how to elegantly filter a list with a varying number of filters, it would be much appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: at least not `==`, but `equals`

Comment: Create your own `equalsOrAny()` method and you will not need your `if`s..

Comment: @PM77-1 could you elaborate, where abouts are you suggesting I should use the `equalsOrAny()` method?

Comment: Can you just apply each filter one at a time? First filter the whole list on X if it's not "any", then filter that resulting list on Y if it's not "any", then filter that list on Z if it's not "any". No need to multiply the combinations of filters unnecessarily.

Comment: @DavidRTribble Yes, he can just chain the filters. I've written a  few test cases and Kes' implementation for `getFilteredList` produces the same outputs as the one in my answer.

Comment: See this. Not an exact fit but it should give you some ideas, specifically reduction of a variable number of predicates over *and*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845574/how-to-dynamically-do-filtering-in-java-8/22855465#22855465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just chain filter calls on the stream for each `String` to filter by, and its corresponding `Model` property.

The `stringFilter` BiFunction ensures that a model will be included in the resulting stream if either the filter for that property is `"any"` or the filter is equal to the value at the appropriate `Model` field.
Since each filter operates on the output of the last, we can ensure that no `Model` that doesn't meet all desired criteria will be included in the returned List.

```
public List<Model> getFilteredList(List<Model> originalList, String x, String y, String z) {

    final BiPredicate<String, Supplier<String>> stringFilter = (filter, stringSupplier) ->
            filter.equals("any") || filter.equals(stringSupplier.get());

    return originalList.stream()
            .filter(model -> stringFilter.test(x, model::getX))
            .filter(model -> stringFilter.test(y, model::getY))
            .filter(model -> stringFilter.test(z, model::getZ))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The `Supplier<T>` type is a functional interface (interface with only 1 method) defined in `java.util.function`, that will return an instance of type `T` when its get() method is called.

When we filter the stream we pass one of the strings to filter by, and the corresponding Model getter to our BiPredicate. The getter is passed by reference and will act as the string source for our `Supplier`.

Comment: Since it is acting as a predicate, might a `BiPredicate<String, Supplier<String>>` be more appropriate instead of `BiFunction<String, Supplier<String>, Boolean>`?

Comment: Good catch! Did not know about the BiPredicate 

Comment: I will have to do some research on `Predicate`'s in java so I fully understand them before I test any solution provided. Thankyou for your help, I'll get back to this later.

Comment: Thankyou for this answer, it motivated me to improve my knowledge in this area and now my eyes have been opened to the power of functional interfaces and lambda expressions. As for your answer @DanielW. it is very readable and explained at a level many can understand, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
private static List<Model> getFilteredList(
    ArrayList<Model> originalList, String x, String y, String z ){

    if(Stream.of(x, y, z).allMatch("any"::equals)) return originalList;

    Stream<Model> s = originalList.stream();
    if(!"any".equals(x)) s = s.filter(m -> m.getX().equals(x));
    if(!"any".equals(y)) s = s.filter(m -> m.getY().equals(y));
    if(!"any".equals(z)) s = s.filter(m -> m.getZ().equals(z));
    return s.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But you should make up your mind regarding the return type. An explicit return type of `ArrayList` suggests that the caller receives a mutable list, but when the list sometimes is the original list and sometimes not, depending on the filter condition, the modifications have undefined semantics, as they might affect the original list or not, which would be disastrous.

So you have to decide whether

- the returned list is not supposed to be modified (don’t declare it to be `ArrayList` and don’t force the creation of an `ArrayList`), that’s what the example above does, or
- the returned list is supposed to be a mutable list without affecting the source, then remove the optimization of returning the original list for all-`"any"`, or
- the original list is supposed to be unused after that, or
- modifications of the returned list should always affect the original list

For c), the contract could not be enforced within the method and for d), it would be impossible to do with the Stream API. So for c) or d), it would be better to modify the original list instead, e.g.

```
private static void filterList(ArrayList<Model> list, String x, String y, String z) {
    Predicate<Model> any = m -> false, effective = any;
    if(!"any".equals(x)) effective = m -> !m.getX().equals(x);
    if(!"any".equals(y)) effective = effective.or(m -> !m.getY().equals(y));
    if(!"any".equals(z)) effective = effective.or(m -> !m.getZ().equals(z));
    if(effective != any) list.removeIf(effective);
}
```

which does not leave any doubts regarding the semantics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper method to construct predicates using a given field and value, then merge those predicates and apply it to a stream:

```
private static ArrayList<Model> getFilteredList(ArrayList<Model> originalList, String x, String y, String z ){
    Predicate<Model> filter = Stream.of(compare(Model::getX, x), compare(Model::getY, y), compare(Model::getZ, z))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .reduce(Predicate::and)
            .orElse($ -> true);

    return originalList.stream()
            .filter(filter)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}

private static Predicate<Model> compare(Function<Model, String> field, String value) {
    return value.equals("any") ? null : m -> field.apply(m).equals(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that will grow linearly, not exponentially, when increasing the number of filtering conditions:

```
private static ArrayList<Model> getFilteredList(ArrayList<Model> originalList, String x, String y, String z){
    Predicate<Model> valueCheck, modelCheck = null;
    if ((valueCheck = (x.equals("any") ? null : item -> x.equals(item.getX()))) != null)
        modelCheck = valueCheck;
    if ((valueCheck = (y.equals("any") ? null : item -> y.equals(item.getY()))) != null)
        modelCheck = (modelCheck != null ? modelCheck.and(valueCheck) : valueCheck);
    if ((valueCheck = (z.equals("any") ? null : item -> z.equals(item.getZ()))) != null)
        modelCheck = (modelCheck != null ? modelCheck.and(valueCheck) : valueCheck);
    if (modelCheck == null)
        return originalList; // No filtering needed
    return originalList.stream().filter(modelCheck).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

It relies on building a compound filter, aka [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html), using the [`and(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) helper method.