# How to convert if-else if chaining block code with multiple filter criteria into single filter criteria with null check?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I do have a `Employee` class & there is a method `getEmployees()` which returns all possible employees. I want to add multiple filter criteria on the same along with different `and` conditions only if incoming params are `not null`.

I've tried following approach which do the filtering part but there are multiple if-else if chaining is happening. Is there any better way to reduce this chaining into single predicate something similar done in [dynamic filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855465/1995161). The chaining code I've is as follow:

Employee class

```
public class Employee{
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String type;

    //getters & setters

}
```

If-else if chaining block:

```
public List<Employee> retrieveEmployees(String searchToken, String fName, String lName, String type){
    //this will retrieve all the available employees 
    List<Employee> employees = getEmployees(); 
    List<Employee> filteredEmployees= new ArrayList<>();

    //perform filtering on the basis of accepted params
    if(searchToken !=null){
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchToken) && emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchToken))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
    else if (fName != null && lName != null && type != null) {
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(lName) && emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (type != null && fname != null && lname == null) {
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (fname != null && lname != null && type == null) {
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(lName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (lname != null && type != null && fname == null) {
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(lName) && emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (fname != null && lname == null && type == null) {
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(fName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (lname != null && fname == null && type == null) {
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(lName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (type != null && fname == null && lname == null) {
        filteredEmployees=employees
        .stream()
        .filter(emp-> emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {
        filteredEmployees=getEmployees();
    }


    return filteredEmployees;
}
```

I've tried something like, but it fails as predicate itself is just doing `or/and` it doesn't satisfy what I've done in `if-else if` block:

```
List<Predicate<Employee>> predicates=Arrays.asList(
            e -> e.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(fName),
            e -> e.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(lName),
            e -> e.getType().equals(type)
    );

Predicate<Employee> compositePredicate = predicates
    .stream()
    .reduce(w -> true, Predicate::or); //tried with 'and' as well

filteredEmployees= employees
    .stream()
    .filter(compositePredicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I'm missing in it ? What's efficient stream predicate chaining approach can be applied ?

Comment: Build your predicate dynamically. Take each search criterion in turn and check it for `null`, if not `null` `.and()` to the composite.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Can you elaborate bit more about the same ? Like any sample code for the same, it will clear me what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have a class `SearchFilter` which will contain all your filter fields like `searchToken`, `fname` etc. and another one `Condition` like:

```
class Condition {
    private Predicate<SearchFilter> searchFilterPredicate;
    private Function<SearchFilter, Predicate<Employee>> function;
}
```

then you can define a static immutable list with all conditions:

```
List<Condition> conditions = Arrays.asList(
    new Condition(sf -> sf.getSearchToken() != null,
                  sf -> emp -> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(sf.getSearchToken()) && emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(sf.getSearchToken())),
    new Condition(sf -> ObjectUtils.allNotNull(sf.getFname(), sf.getLname(), sf.getType()),
                  sf -> emp-> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(sf.getFname()) && emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(sf.getLname()) && emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(sf.getType()))
    //...
);
```

and finally the `retrieveEmployees` method

```
public List<Employee> retrieveEmployees(String searchToken, String fname, String lname, String type){
    List<Employee> employees = getEmployees();
    SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter(searchToken, fname, lname, type);

    Optional<Predicate<Employee>> firstCondition = conditions.stream()
            .filter(condition -> condition.getSearchFilterPredicate().test(searchFilter))
            .findFirst()
            .map(condition -> condition.getFunction().apply(searchFilter));

    return firstCondition.map(employeePredicate -> employees.stream()
                .filter(employeePredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .orElse(employees);
}
```

**Another solution** might be checking each filter field and add it to predicate

```
List<Employee> retrieveEmployees(String searchToken, String fname, String lname, String type){
    List<Employee> employees = getEmployees();
    if(searchToken != null) {
        return employees
                .stream()
                .filter(emp -> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchToken) && emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchToken))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
    Predicate<Employee> predicate = employee -> true;

    if(type != null) {
        predicate = predicate.and(emp -> emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type));
    }
    if(lname != null) {
        predicate = predicate.and(emp -> emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(lname));
    }
    if(fname != null) {
        predicate = predicate.and(emp -> emp.getFName().equalsIgnoreCase(fname));
    }

    return employees.stream()
             .filter(predicate)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: It's better than what I've done. But can we do it better than this ? Here we are  joining what I've done in if-else block & respective filter condition.

Comment: @AshwinK I've added another solution and I think it's what Boris the Spider was saying

Comment: It means I'll have to add all if-else criteria & respective predicate, right ? Ex., `if (lname != null && type != null && fname == null) { predicate = predicate.and(emp-> emp.getLName().equalsIgnoreCase(lName) && emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) }` Is it correct ?

Comment: @AshwinK no, just check each criteria separately as I did in example. There is no need to check for example `fname == null` or two criteria in one if statement and predicate, because in the end you'll have a composite predicate. Btw, even IDE is telling me that `fname == null` is useless. Also you should have a separate case for `searchToken`.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian this make sense. I did exactly same after your prototype, but missed to return at searchToken check.

Comment: The second solution is clear and easy to read - the first is, in my opinion, even messier than the OPs solution. If you remove the first solution you will have my upvote. Also note that this `predicate = predicate.and(emp -> emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type))` is duplicated 3 times; a little bit of refactoring and you'll have some really clean code.

Comment: @Adrian For your second solutions (**Another Solution**) sometimes I'm getting null values as well & those are getting added to `return` list. Why that might be happening ? I'm unable to debug the issue. Even though in `employees` there is no such null values object (nor any object's param is null)

Comment: @AshwinK you saying that `getEmployees()` returns null values? If so why doesn't it fail with NPE in predicate? Perhaps all filter fields are also null? if so then just add a second stream filter `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: Yeah, later I explored the same & added non null filter. Thanks again.